# Longest sentence with each letter repeated n times

Tags: wordplay, open-ended, letters

**Inspiration:**
*This question was inspired by [Word sets with no repeating letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/word-sets-with-no-repeating-letters)*

**Rules:**

- Sentences can be of any length.
- Every letter used in this sentence, must be used *n* times.
- *n* can be any number.
- Capitals/Punctuation do not count.
- No dialogue!

**Objective:**
*The objective is to find the longest sentence which abides by the rules and clarifications.*

**Length Measuring:**
*The way your sentence is measured is by characters, including spaces, and punctuation!*

**Further Clarifications:**

- The sentence cannot consist of mainly the same word repeated, or the same 2, etc.
- You cannot make up new words or names.
- It has to be in English.
- No uncommon names.

**Checking your answer:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tLcvk2o4/

---

**Current Best:**

**Sentence:** I'm the master's nightmarish, gorgonian hatemonger, his moth-eaten gonorrhoea, smothering mightiest heroism, thrashing egomania's (or, to me, ignorant mismanagement's) strong-arm mishmash or staggering high treason.

**Length:** 215

**N:** 16

**Letters:** AEGHIMNORST (11 total)

**Current Winner:** uri zarfaty

---

The answer format should be the same format as the Current Best section!

*If your answer does not beat the current best, but you still wish to post it, feel free, you may still get +1s!*

Comment: I think giving an example would clarify the question. It seems a little confusing to me.

Comment: @CyanogenCX I have no examples... If I think of one I'll post.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Would it be like if this was a sentence: go go go ----
each letter is repeated three times

Comment: @CyanogenCX Technically yes, but that isn't really a sentence...

Comment: Ok I think your edit made me understand it.

Comment: @CyanogenCX I just fixed the formatting (I also added a new rule after your comment)

Comment: I think "Letters included: ____" would be more intuitive and easier to answer. (or CyanogenCX could say B,D,F,G,H,I,J,K,N,O,P,Q,R,S,U,V,W,X,Z)

Comment: @Quark True ${}{}$

Comment: @CyanogenCX You could use semicolons... If you don't mind, I'll post that.

Comment: Any sentence that repeats no letters then combines with an anagram of that sentence meets the requirements for this problem, yes?

Comment: @CyanogenCX I think you're thinking of ["Buffalo buffalo buffalo."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Comment: @user3334690 yeah but buffalo has much more f's than any letter, and each letter needs to be repeated the same amount of times.

Comment: Also you should clarify the rules so uncommon names aren't allowed, otherwise I could make a name up like mr. aghgzppewrmugb just to make my sentence work.

Comment: @Cyan Good catch, adding to clarifications.

Comment: Along with an English rule.

Comment: These are surprisingly fun to do!  Here's a quick little helper to keep track of what letters you need:  http://jsfiddle.net/tLcvk2o4/  C'mon, someone beat 71!

Comment: @DevOfZot Well a puzzle should be fun in my opinion

Comment: Feel free to link to that jsfiddle in the post since it's buried down here.

Comment: I was disappointed to see the rule about not repeating the same word many times. Otherwise it's not too hard to find an infinitely recursive sentence: "cows who like cats who like cats who like cats who like cats... hit kale"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Sentence**

> I'm the master's nightmarish, gorgonian hatemonger, his moth-eaten gonorrhoea, smothering mightiest heroism, thrashing egomania's (or, to me, ignorant mismanagement's) strong-arm mishmash or staggering high treason.

**Length**: 215

**N**: 16

**Letters**: AEGHIMNORST (11 total)

Produced by interleaving and manually modifying multiple computer-generated anagram fragments. With more work it should be possible both to improve the readability and extend it further.

Answer (score 15):

A blatant homage to the mods:

**Sentence**: Our rangers of the null postings are leaping up, high atop this fluff.

**Length**: 71

**n**: 4

**Letters**: aefghilnoprstu

Answer (score 11):

Sentence: My cat ate my cell.

Length: 19

n: 2

Letters included: m, y, c, a, t, e, l

Answer (score 11):

**Sentence:** Step on no pets!

**Length:** 16

**n:** 2

**Letters:** ENOPST

Answer (score 10):

EDIT:

It took me some time and a lot of dict.leo.org as I am no native speaker. Here is my second try:

**Twenty-two numb lizards yearly assist wizards who summon the chill, cold blizzard, when my muzzy church buddy won me no crab cub - be it!**

**Length:** 137

**N:** 6

**Letters:** A, B, C, D, E, H, I, L, M, N, O, R, S, T, U, W, Y, Z (18 total)

--- DEPRECATED ---

> My mum's wild buddy Yannik B. was widely known to tell rumors about
>   trekkie bars.

Letters: a,b,d,e,i,k,l,m,n,o,r,s,t,u,w,y

n: 4

Length : 81

Comment: "You cannot make up ne words or names."

Comment: I read this as 'Do not invent new words.'. Yannik is a totally normal word, a name.

Answer (score 9):

*Updates from comments:*

```
Enid, MY goat, ate my dingo. (length 28, 10 letters: credit to Muqo)
My snide goat ate my dingos. (length 28, 11 letters)
```

---

**Sentence:** Ed, my goat, ate my dog.

**Length:** 24

**n:** 2

**Letters:** ADEGMOTY

---

Bonus:

**Sentence:** Keats takes Steak Skate stake.

(*Steak Skate* is a combination skating rink and steakhouse. They hold an annual competition, and Keats won this year's stake.)

**Length:** 30

**n:** 5

**Letters:** AEKST

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yeah, well, **Enid, MY goat, ate my dingo.**

Comment: @Muqo Sure, but **My *snide* goat ate my dingos.**

Comment: I wish I could go to Steak Skate..

Answer (score 9):

Not  sure if the convention is to add a new answer or edit my old one, but here's a new and rather saucy attempt:

---

**Sentence**: The tight-shoed thigh-slapping puzzle nudist, polo pants unzipped and full of gaffing stuff, laughs off a dozen glazed pizza-sized doughnut holes!

**Length**: 146

**n**: 8

**Letters**: adefghilnopstuz

---

Also, I updated that tool a bit, use http://jsfiddle.net/uuef3bf7/ if you like.

Comment: I kinda don't want to accept this...

Answer (score 6):

**Sentence:** I hit a heat blob's sole.

(Yes, blobs of heat have shoes too!)

**Length:** 25

**n:** 2

**Letters:** ABEHILOST

Answer (score 4):

Sentence:

> **I buy my stark musk, roast rusk in milk, dark blue bow, reed, bat, wind bell, stud, two lemon on my windy way.**

Length: Letters=**80**

Blank space= **22**

Comma= **7**

Full stop=1

n=**5**

Letters used=**16** (a b d e i k l m n o r s t u w y)

Comment: @Geobits, thanx, fixed, I think this will not get accepted for 2 "my"

Comment: Nice! You should add in the total character count (since that's the main scoring method). I count it as 110. I don't think using a single word twice will invalidate it, though. It's definitely not "*mainly* the same word repeated".

Comment: Eh, A for effort but this is more of a list of words than a sentence.  It isn't even grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

I got:

Sentence: Tales steal Tesla Sattle sales, settles ala.

Length: 44

n: 7

Letters: aelst

Answer (score 1):

Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz.

Length: 26.

n: 1.

letters: Every letter of the alphabet.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Yes, they are. (The former is a rounded valley; the latter is an alternate spelling of "vexed".) This is a well-known pangram.