# The Autonumerigram Challenge

Tags: wordplay, formation-of-numbers, open-ended, calculation-puzzle

Some phrases both refer to a number, *n*, and are comprised of *n* alphabetic characters. I call any such phrase an ***autonumerigram***.

For example,

- ***four*** has 4 letters
- ***seven plus seven*** has 14 letters
- ***fifteen times one*** has 15 letters
- ***one followed by six*** has 16 letters
- ***one before two*** has 12 letters
- ***four before twenty*** has 16 letters

The challenge is to discover the longest and most interesting autonumerigram!

This challenge is open-ended, of course, and I will award the coveted green check to the current longest submission (provided that it's not cheap). I will, however, upvote any interesting submission, regardless of length, so don't be discouraged if you can't discover a long one!

---

Guidelines:

1. **Syntactically, your phrase should be substitutable in "__ is n".**

   For example, all of my above examples fit this context:

   > ***four*** is 4
   >   ***seven plus seven*** is 14
   >   ***fifteen times one*** is 15
   >   ***one followed by six*** is 16
   >   ***one before two*** is 12
   >   ***four before twenty*** is 16
2. **Avoid extraneous and cheap additions.**

   The phrase ***eight and nine, maybe*** does have 17 letters, but the ***maybe*** is rather extraneous and cheap.
3. **Avoid cheap recursion.**

   By appending ***and six*** to ***four*** repeatedly, we can create a phrase for any number of the form *6n+4*. For example,

   - ***four and six and six and six*** has 22 letters
4. **Strive for human readability and comprehension.**

   If an autonumerigram is very long but hard for a human to parse, it loses points in my book.
    <sub>*(Guidelines may be altered or added as the need arises.)*</sub>

Comment: Perhaps this is too broad? I based it on other open-ended, find-the-longest-type puzzles. For example, http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/longest-sentence-with-each-letter-repeated-n-times.

Comment: I've downvoted because this is opinion-based - "most interesting" is inherently subjective. I suspect any fix would be too broad. (Also, IMO that question you linked should be closed.)

Comment: @Deusovi, "most interesting" is definitely opinion-based. That's why I explicitly stated that the green check goes to the longest (provided it abides by the guidelines—although you might make the case that these, too, lack objectivity). In any event, I like these kind of open-ended puzzles and think they fit nicely on the site; maybe it's a topic for meta...

Comment: Okay. Then it's too broad unless you precisely define "cheap recursion". I don't think they fit nicely on the site at all - there's a reason Code Golf has such stringent rules for what counts as an answer and how to pick the best one.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one that is fairly interesting, and reasonably long.

**255**

> *The first prime raised to the zeroth power plus itself raised to the first power plus itself raised to the power of two plus itself raised to the third power plus itself raised to the fourth power plus itself raised to the fifth power plus itself raised to the sixth power plus itself raised to the seventh power* has 255 letters: $2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7=255$

Comment: Maybe you could include an equation corresponding to the text, just so it's easier to check?

Comment: err... ok I guess, I thought this particular one was pretty straightforward binary

Comment: You're right, but it might establish a nice convention for future submissions.