# four word starter sets for multi-wordle games

Tags: wordle

For "multi-Wordle" games like Quordle and Octordle, it's nice to have an "opening book" of non-overlapping words that cover the most common letters.

I have a few three word sets that do well in Quordle, but Octordle almost always requires another clue and I'm having trouble composing a four word set.

The set should use all of {ACDEGHILNORSTUY} plus any 5 of {BFJKMPVW} (i.e. not {QXZ}).

Comment: Should the set to be formed be a five word set?

Comment: For 5-word sets, see [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/8212/20814)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By modifying the approach in my answer [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123459/can-you-employ-all-26-letters-using-three-11-letter-three-10-letter-or-three-9/123475#123475), I found thousands of solutions, including:

> dormy fling jaups vetch

You can also make "fetch" happen:

> fetch groks laund wimpy

And $15$ with two particularly relevant words fixed:

> ```
>  cheat flump vying words
>  cheat flimp gunky words
>  cheat flung jimpy words
>  cheat fling jumpy words
>  cheat flunk pigmy words
>  bumpy cheat fling words
>  blunk cheat pigmy words
>  cheat jumby pling words
>  blunk cheat gimpy words
>  cheat flunk gimpy words
>  cheat plumb vying words
>  bingy cheat flump words
>  cheat fling jumby words
>  bungy cheat flimp words
>  blimp cheat gunky words
> ```

Explicitly, the modifications are:

- Restrict word.list to five-letter words that do not contain q, x, or z.
- Change the $3$ to $4$ in the equality constraint.
- Fix $y_\ell=1$ for the $15$ required letters.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure that a computer search will turn out many answers, but I had a go by hand and found the following set of four words:

> chump
>  knows
>  girly
>  fated or bated

And here are three others:

> champ joked rusty fling
>  clamp brown gusty hiked
>  black fight pervy sound